# ArcPy not applying geographic transformation

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

For several georeferenced images (.tif) that are in a wrong projection (3857) I want to reproject them to the correct one (28992). In ArcGIS Pro I can use Raster Export, set the correct CRS and the geographic transformation (Amersfoort_To_WGS_1984_NTv2). This works perfectly.

But since we're talking about hundreds of images I want to do this in Arcpy. For this I am using the following script:

```
import arcpy
import time

start_time = time.time()
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r'MyString'

rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters()print(rasterlist)

for x in rasterlist:
arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = arcpy.SpatialReference('Projected Coordinate Systems/National Grids/Europe/RD New')
arcpy.env.geographic_Transformation = 'Amersfoort_To_WGS_1984_NTv2'
arcpy.management.CopyRaster('{}'.format(x), '{}_export.tif'.format(x[:-4]))
print('{} is done'.format(x))

print('All rasters have been converted!')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

The above script does not seem to be applying the transformation and thereby projecting the images some 100 meters south.

Does anyone know what I should be doing to get this working like it does in ArcGIS Pro itself?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the help file for the [Copy Raster tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/copy-raster.htm#GUID-A2DC666A-F101-4CF5-868C-76C7186092FC) you will see that there is the Apply transformation parameter. Now look at your code, you have only provided the two mandatory parameters and not told the tool to apply the transformation. You need to get better at understanding what the parameter section of the help file for any tool is telling you.

You could also use the Project Raster tool.

Comment: I have tried adding the transform parameter to my code, but that doesn't make a difference. At least the only this the docs are telling me is that I have to add "transform = 'Transform'" to the code.

Comment: Hmm, may be your raster does not have the associated transformation supplied with it? Try using the Project Raster tool instead.

Comment: I guess that's it then. The Project Raster tool does seem to work! However now I am running into this error: "ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters". I made the path a raw string. I am guessing that the spaces in the file names are causing the error. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Yes try a file path something simple like c:\temp\mydata.tif to test that's the problem. I find building the whole path is more stable and obvious than relying on the workspace environment.

Comment: I managed to fix it by using python's replace function. Thanks again!